# почему в терминале выводит ошибку line 9, in <module> total_num = num1 / num2 ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Tags: python

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 30
total_num = num1 / num2
print(f'{total_num:,.2f}')

while num2  != 0 :
    num1 += 1
    num2 -= 1
    total_num = num1 / num2
    print(f'{total_num:,.2f}')
```

Comment: А когда в цикле при проверке num2 равен 1, что происходит дальше?

Comment: последний вывод функции print (30), после чего и выскакивает ошибка.

Comment: не понимаю, в чем проблема, потому что я обозначил в цикле условие, и не должна происходить итерация в случае, если num2 = 0

Comment: Еще раз и медленно, как для депутата... num2 = 1. ***Что произойдет при выполнении `num2 -= 1`?*** Теперь достаточно понятно или все равно надо разжевывать?

Comment: как жеж, если `num2 = 1`  условие выполняется и далее выполняется -1, для отладки, перед делением, напиши `if num2==0: print('равно нулю')`

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны переместить строки

```py
    num1 += 1
    num2 -= 1
```

из начала цикла в конец, чтобвы сначала всё считать, потом изменять числа, и чтобы когда `num2` станет нулём, цикл остановился.